# What is the value of the variable? int iNum = 10/3

Tags: java, types, int, double, primitive-types

Isn't the data type int only used for integers? 10/3 is a fraction therefore a decimal. Does this mean that it will create an error?

Comment: umm...why don't you try it and see ? you can put a 10/3 into int. Only the whole part is stored, that is 3.

Comment: Have you tried by yourself before asking?

Comment: You mean “rational” where you wrote “decimal”.

Answer (score 2):

It depends on the language. For your example (Java), it will be rounded towards zero (also called a "truncate" operation). So the value becomes 3. Try it out yourself:

```
int i = 10 / 3;
System.out.println(i); // Displays 3

int j  = -10 / 3;
System.out.println(j); // Displays -3

double k = 10 / 3;
System.out.println(k) // Displays 3.00

double m = ((double)10) / 3;
System.out.println(k) // Displays 3.33

double m = 10.0 / 3;
System.out.println(k) // Displays 3.33
```

There are actually two operations going on in each case. Considering the first example,

Step 1:
Calculate the value of the right-hand side `[Integer 10]` divided by `[Integer 3]`. Answer is `[Integer 3]` as described above.

Step 2:
Assign this RHS value `[Integer 3]` to the left-hand side. `[Integer 3]` is assigned to `[Integer i]`. So i becomes equal to 3.

Because the operation is done in two steps, the third operation using `double` also gives 3.00, not 3.33. The precision has already been lost by the time Step 2 starts.

Comment: It won't be rounded down. Try with `11/3`.

Comment: ohh I understand, what about double casting a double data type, for example: double dNum = (double)(14/5);

Comment: @AdamArold It is rounded to zero, but `11/3 == 3` and `-11/3 == -3`

Comment: @atomicno6 Casting doesn't change the result of `14/5 = 2` cast to `double` is now `2.0` What you need is `(double) 14/5 = 14.0/5 = 2.8`

Comment: Rounding to zero is basically the same as discarding the numbers after the decimal point.

Comment: @AdamArold what do you mean? Why won't it be rounded down to an integer? The value of `11/3` is still 3. The operaative word is "rounded **down**".

Comment: @metacubed "truncated" may be more appropriate, consider `-11/3 == -3` as per Peter's comment. "rounded down" implies `-3.66 -> -4`

Comment: @AdamArold "rounded down" does not mean the same as "rounded".  "rounded" by itself means to the nearest integer, "rounded down" means non-integers are rounded to the next *lower* integer, and "rounded up" of course means to the next *higher* integer.  But it's best to avoid the latter two terms when negative numbers are involved.  The best terms would be "rounded" which means rounded to the nearest integer, "rounded toward zero" or "truncated", "floor", and "ceiling".

Comment: @Nataly Carbonell - You should read a book on basic java and try to learn by experimenting. Good luck.

Comment: Your use of the word "floor" is incorrect.  "Floor" **always** results in a number that is `<=` the operand, i.e. floor(-3.1) is -4.  It is not the same as rounding toward zero.  +1 for your third example which trips a lot of people up.

Answer (score 1):

In the code, 10/3 is *not* a fraction. Java does not have primitive fractions.

Rather, it is an expression representing the *integer* 10 divided by the *integer* 3. Since neither type causes promotion of the division to floating-point (ie. neither is a float/double) then *integer division* is used, where the result will also be an *integer*.

There are thus no floating-point types in the question and the result is 3 (an *integer*, which is assignable directly to an integer variable). As others have pointed out, the result of such a division *acts* like a "round to zero" or "truncation" operation.